# ReactJS component HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-video, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to have have video in my web page using HTML `<video>` tag using ReactJS and JSX. Right now nothing is playing even though my component has the path to the file

IntroVideo this.props:

```
{
  introVideo: "assets/media/Cherngloong_website_intro_Uz921bT.mp4",
  muted: "true"
}
```

Component:

```
class IntroVideo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <video className="video-container video-container-overlay" autoPlay="true" loop muted={ this.props.muted }>
                    <source src={ this.props.introVideo } type="video/mp4" />
                </video>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Here is what I see in the developer tools:

```
<video class="video-container video-container-overlay" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0">
    <source type="video/mp4" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0" src="assets/media/Cherngloong_website_intro_Uz921bT.mp4">
</video>
```

In the developer tools, if I right click the `src` value and click on `"Open link in new tab"`, the video would play in the new tab. So I believe it the path to the file is correct.

I am doing the same thing for another Component but it is for an image and it works fine:

About this.props:

```
{
  aboutImg: "assets/media/The_Lion_Dances_Celebrate_Happy_New_Year_Clipart.jpg"
}
```

Component:

```
class About extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        };
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="about-container">
                <div id="about-img-container">
                    <img src={ this.props.aboutImg } alt="about_img"/>
                </div>
                <div id="about-text-container">
                    <p>
                        Message
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Developer Tools:

```
<div id="about-container" data-reactid=".0.1.1">
    <div id="about-img-container" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0">
        <img alt="about_img" data-reactid=".0.1.1.0.0" src="assets/media/The_Lion_Dances_Celebrate_Happy_New_Year_Clipart.jpg">
    </div>
    <div id="about-text-container" data-reactid=".0.1.1.1">
        <p data-reactid=".0.1.1.1.0">Message</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What specifically isn't working? Have you tried `autoplay="autoplay"` instead, or added `controls="controls"` so that you can click the video to start it?

Comment: Looks like in JSX it's supposed to be `autoplay` with no value, or `autoplay={true}`

Comment: @loganfsmyth tried `autoPlay` and `autoPlay={true}` no luck =[

Comment: So what specifically isn't working? Can you see the preview image, but it won't play? Did you try my first set of suggestions?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I tried your suggestions and no success =[ I cannot see any video at all. As if there is no `src` Here is what I see on my browser and dev tools: http://postimg.org/image/b0u3swswh/  http://postimg.org/image/ccg3pz9ld/

Comment: @loganfsmyth just tried hard coding the value into the video src and it worked. However I'm not sure why using `{this.props.introVideo}` didn't work. I checked my network tab in dev tools and there is not request for the intro video asset

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bad path.  The generated html seems to be fine.  I tested it here:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video

The video rendered fine, and all I did was change the src.

```
<video className="video-container video-container-overlay" autoPlay="" loop="" muted="" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0">
  <source type="video/mp4" data-reactid=".0.1.0.0.0" src="mov_bbb.mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Video React](https://video-react.js.org/)

a Component for playing video would be a better option as it has lots of customisation

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I add the "?" at the end of the video url and it acts well.
I got the same case with the url by using the video in aws s3 bucket.
So I used the url as "assets/media/Cherngloong_website_intro_Uz921bT.mp4?"

Answer (score 0):

put the video in the public/videos folder and write the src as below